# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, arraylist

I have two methods, one stores values into the arraylist i.e Button_1Click().The other method NextClick() retrieves data from the arraylist and stores it into a textbox.
I get a array index out of bounds error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
int i = 0;
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        @"data source=D:\asp\data\test.mdb;";
    conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM D", conn);
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dReader.Read())
    {
        String temp = dReader[1].ToString();
        list.Add(temp);
        temp = dReader[2].ToString();
        list.Add(temp);

    }

    dReader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
protected void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Carname.Text = list[i] as String;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: And then, what happened then? You dont think you should check the index value of **i** before you just read it from **list[i]**? Something like **if (list.Count <= i) return;**

Comment: It puzzles me that people that even manages to work with databases don't see why simple things like this don't work.

Comment: when i used a if statement to check i is less than list.count, I don't get the error but nothing gets displayed in the textbox.

Comment: @ares because there is nothing more to be displayed, there are no more data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look buddy, every time you press any of the buttons, this bit here executes:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
int i = 0;
```

It means that they will always go back to their original state when you click a button. You can try it yourself -> put a break point on any of those lines and go ahead and press a button.

Comment: And why is that code executed every time the button is clicked?

Comment: @JuliánUrbano Just in case you're really asking, this code is always executed because every time an event executes you get a new instance of the page class. ASP.NET is stateless.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my button1_click method and used a listbox instead. Now it works!

```
while (dReader.Read())
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dReader[1].ToString()+""+dReader[2].ToString());

    }
```